# ASP.NET WebForms with MVC localization issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, webforms

I have a mixed project: WebForms with ASP.NET MVC2 and is running OK.
I have done [this tutorial](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) on separate MVC Project and localization is working fine.

However, when I want to apply localization (mentioned above) in my mixed project, it seems to be ignored. It doesn't matter what I set in global.asax file (de-DE, fr-FR, pl-PL) always get en-EN or en-GB. This is really strange. web.config is correct and doesn't force the localization.

Any clues why it is ignored in mixed project?

Comment: I think that I found the answer...
While having code below in global.asax for MVC project is fine

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");


It will not work WebForms - methods above are internal to the page and can be used in the page only.

Answer (score 0):

Just happend to me.

My resources project contains `Forms.resx` and `Forms.fr-fr.resx`.
The neutral culture is set to `en-us`.

My ASP MVC 2 project has a reference to the previous one. No neutral culture was set.
Implementing localization caused validation not to validate anymore.

Setting the same neutral culture in the web project made stuff work.